# Colorbar rendering issue with mpld3 vs pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I have an issue when rendering a figure with a colorbar with mpld3 but it works fine with pyplot. This is how it is supposed to look like (figure rendered with `plt.show()`):

[image: figure rendered with plt.show()]

when using `mpld3.show()` to display the plot I get the colorbar looking like this:

[image: figure rendered with mpld3.show()]

notice that:

- the colors are inverted (when compared to the correct plot)
- it starts at 10ˆ-7 instead of 10^-6
- it is shifted to the side (down and to the right)

This is the piece of code I am using, only uncommenting `plt.show()` to `mpld3.show()` and vice versa:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, summed_data, cmap=custom_cmap, norm=norm)
    fig.colorbar(pcm, location='left')
    ax.set_xlabel(x_name + ' [cm]')
    ax.set_ylabel(y_name + ' [cm]')
    ax.set_title('Plot title')
```

I am not showing how X, Y, cmap and norm are defined because I don't think the problem is there, but I don't mind adding it.

Comment: Could you please share more lines of your code, making it clear how you make "custom_cmap" and "norm".